# How to configure the conditional beans provided in Spring 4 using XML configuration file

Tags: java, spring

I would like to configure the conditional bean shown in below example using XMl Spring configuration instead of going through annotations . Is it possible to achieve the conditional beans through XML configuration ?

```
public class TestCondition1 implements Condition
{
  @Override
  public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata)
  {
    return context.getEnvironment().getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows");
  }
}

@Configuration
public class BeanTestConfiguration
{
  @Bean(name="TesService")
  @Conditional(TestCondition1.class)
  public BeanTestConditionService getTestService()
  {
    return new BeanTestConditionService();
  }
}

public class BeanTestConditionService
{
  public BeanTestConditionService()
  {
    System.out.println("I am in test setvice");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Not supported yet](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10969), and probably wont for sometime

> Eventually closing this as Won't Fix since the whole condition model
>   has really been designed with annotations in mind, and is generally a
>   better fit there. If any common needs remain for XML configuration,
>   we'd rather fine-tune the declarative profile model which is already
>   available in XML.

Comment: Of course one could work around that by using some sort of factory bean that makes the whole decisions and then configure the bean from the factory method... But that's of course only working around xml config limitations, not working with xml config.